# What programs are run when in safe mode and waking up from sleep?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, sleep-wake, crash

I have been having some terrible issues with my MacBook Pro Retina in that it randomly shuts down within 5 minutes of booting up. I seem to have isolated a problem free environment to safe mode immediately after booting up. (i.e. the problem exists when in "normal" boot, as well as in safe boot when the computer had previously gone to sleep.) Since I know the problem is started when the computer wakes up from sleep in safe mode, is there somewhere I can check to see which programs are only run then and not when the machine boots up?

Comment: Basically, only Apple software runs on safe boot. One test is to make a new admin account & test there, see if the offender is the same for all users or just one.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this exact problem occurs whenever OS X is run, in any configuration. What I mean by that is that no matter how many clean installs, without any logging in of previous users, or logging in to iCloud, or other versions of OS X installed(I have even tried Mavericks), the problem persists.